# on check box check send value to partial view and update it mvc 3

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

i have two partial view one is having a 5 checkbox (for filtering) and another will display the filtered data.

```
<input type="checkbox" data-toggle="checkbox" id="2000-5000"/>Rs.2000-Rs.5000
<input type="checkbox" data-toggle="checkbox" id="2000-5000"/>Rs.2000-Rs.5000
```

and with help of jquery am sending the request to controller..

```
    public PartialViewResult PhonesPartail(int? id,string where)
    {
        var list = paginateRsult(id, "", where).ToList();
        ViewData["totalpages"] = totalPages;
        return PartialView("_phonelist",list);
    }
```

and the jquery

```
 $(document).on("change", ".price-checkbox input[type=checkbox]", function () {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            var prange = $(this).attr("id");
            var parray = prange.split('-');
            var whereclause = "price>=" + parray[0] + " and price <=" + parray[1];
            $.ajax({
                url: '../../Phones/PhonesPartail',
                data: { where: whereclause },
                type: 'POST',
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#phone-list").append(data);

                }
            });
        }
    });
```

now the list which is returned , is getting added to the div with entire html page.. means again the html page is getting added in the div..

any solution..

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

use html() function of jquery
It will paste data returned by partial view in to a div rather then appending it to div

```
$("#phone-list").html(data);
```